# How can I display a large body to a spring boot + thymeleaf template without hitting OutOfMemoryException

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an app I am converting to use Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. One of the servlets extracts data from a log file on the server (which is locked down to developers) so we can diagnose certain types of failures. Most of these log extracts are relatively small, but some can end up many tens to hundreds of megabytes. Admittedly, this is a blunt weapon but I'm not looking to make it smarter, just get it moved to the new framework.

The old jsp page just emitted html to set up the page, then ran a script that was a grep/awk combo and streamed the output, and finished it off with the closing html. The thymeleaf template is laid out the same, but because I'm using a @RestController, I'm collecting the output from the log scrape to assign it to a model parameter. That's when I run in to the memory problem.

The question is how should I be doing this? I hate giving up the thymeleaf template, but for this page, it's not strictly necessary. It's mostly buying me consistent styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Stream of the log file like Files.lines(Paths.get(logfileName)) in your controller and put the stream's iterator in your model. Thymeleaf can process an iterator using th:each.

Comment: This sounds good, but...something like this (with a lot missing)
`BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(uploadDir, whatFile)));
lineIter = in.lines().iterator();
modelMap.put("lineIter", lineIter);`
is resulting in "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".

Comment: Can you include the exception's stack trace?

Comment: Also, you mention you are using a rest controller, which I didn't catch when first read, which implies a web service call but you are putting the data into the model which typically isn't done in a rest controller. Are you loading a thymeleaf template and calling the rest controller for the data via javascript, jquery, etc.? If this is the case you can look into using a ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>. Can you add more of your code so we can better understand the situation?

Comment: Oops, yes, I got that OOM, but it was from a latent bug in a different place. My bad for being lazy and not being sure of this. I've marked the answer as correct as it certainly seems to have resolved my issue. I'm not quite sure how Spring Boot is going to deal with the file reader that is not explicitly closed.

Comment: Good point. You could derive a new wrapper Iterator<T> class named something like AutoCloseAtEndIterator<T> whose hasNext() performs a close when delegate.hasNext() returns false. This assumes you consume the whole stream and don't quit before the end of stream. That may be the best you can do.

Comment: Thanks! That was quick and easy to do. I kept thinking in terms of some callback which doesn't exist, but your suggestion is perfect.